# Need advice on program logic

Tags: c#, .net

The program comes to the page and makes pressing buttons

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Bot
{
    public partial class FormWindow : Form
    {
        Random rnd;
        Settings settingsForm;
        Timer tm;
        CallTimers callTimers;

        public FormWindow()
        {
            rnd = new Random();
            settingsForm = new Settings();
            tm = new Timer();
            tm.Tick += new EventHandler(tm_Tick);
            wb = new WebBrowser();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (wb.Document.GetElementById("login-email") != null)
            {
                wb.Document.GetElementById("login-email").InnerText = settingsForm.tEmail.Text;
                wb.Document.GetElementById("login-password").InnerText = settingsForm.tPassword.Text;
                Method_1("button luxury")[0].InvokeMember("click");
            }

               CallMethodAfterDelay(KrysomahHunting, 5000, tm);

                if (wb.Url.AbsoluteUri == "http://www.moswar.ru/metro/" && wb.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    wb.Stop();
                    method_2("c", "Выследить Крысомаху")[0].InvokeMember("click");
                    Method_1(new string[] { "button" })[0].InvokeMember("click");
                }
        }

        //go to page 
        public void GoPage(string string_9, string string_10)
        {
            this.wb.Stop();
            string additionalHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + Environment.NewLine;
            this.wb.Navigate(string_9, "", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string_10), additionalHeaders);
        }


        public List<HtmlElement> Method_1(params string[] ClassNames)
        {
            List<HtmlElement> list = new List<HtmlElement>();
            foreach (HtmlElement htmlElement in wb.Document.All)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ClassNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    string b = ClassNames[i];
                    if (htmlElement.GetAttribute("className") == b)
                    {
                        list.Add(htmlElement);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }


        private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.settingsForm.tEmail.Text == "" || this.settingsForm.tPassword.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Отсутствует логин и\\или пароль для входа на сервер МосВара.\nВвести их можно, нажав на кнопку \"Настройки\".", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                return;
            }
            wb.Navigate("http://www.moswar.ru");
        }

        private void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((MethodInvoker)tm.Tag).Invoke();
            tm.Stop();
        }

        //go to page through time 
         public void CallMethodAfterDelay(MethodInvoker MethodToCall, int Delay,Timer tm)
       {
           tm.Interval = Delay;
           tm.Tag = MethodToCall;
           tm.Start();
       }
        public void KrysomahHunting()
        {
            GoPage("http://www.moswar.ru/metro/", "");
        }

        private List<HtmlElement> method_2(string string_9, string string_10)
        {
            List<HtmlElement> list = new List<HtmlElement>();
            foreach (HtmlElement htmlElement in this.wb.Document.All)
            {
                if (htmlElement.GetAttribute("className") == string_9 && htmlElement.InnerText != null && htmlElement.InnerText.IndexOf(string_10) != -1)
                {
                    list.Add(htmlElement);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

    }
}
```

Help how to articulate the logic

In this piece of code

```
private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (wb.Document.GetElementById("login-email") != null)
            {
                wb.Document.GetElementById("login-email").InnerText = settingsForm.tEmail.Text;
                wb.Document.GetElementById("login-password").InnerText = settingsForm.tPassword.Text;
                Method_1("button luxury")[0].InvokeMember("click");
            }

               CallMethodAfterDelay(KrysomahHunting, 5000, tm);

                if (wb.Url.AbsoluteUri == "http://www.moswar.ru/metro/" && wb.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    wb.Stop();
                    method_2("c", "Выследить Крысомаху")[0].InvokeMember("click");
                    Method_1(new string[] { "button" })[0].InvokeMember("click");
                }

        }
```

When the program comes to the method

```
method_2("c", "Выследить Крысомаху")[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

throws Exception ArgumentOutRangeException

I supposethat this couldbe caused by

```
private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
```

Heconstantly checks.Ifapagethatexecute methods .And because the method once already done its job, there is no longer the values

And so we get an exception ArgumentOutRangeException. Help how to make the logic for this case!

Comment: what is the question here?  It seems like a giant wall of code.

Comment: does your method2 return a array?

Comment: To help with a question to see the code!

Comment: Debug the code first. That will tell you why it's going wrong. You can then decide how to fix it. We can't do that for you because we don't know the business requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add a check in on that method call?

```
var method2 = method_2("c", "...");
if (method2.Count > 0)
    method2[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: How to make that event methods in wb_DocumentCompleted worked 1 time 
After downloading the pages There is a constant calling methods ?

Comment: I don't follow your comment? could you clarify? I'm not sure where you are hooking up the wb_DocumentCompleted method either, but that might help.

Comment: How to make that event wb_DocumentCompleted . Call methods only 1 time. But not always when the page loads?

Comment: wb_DocumentCompleted should only fire once on the DocumentCompleted event. I'm not sure why it's firing multiple times.

Comment: Because, when the page is fully loaded or reloaded webbrowser event fires again . How can I fix?Can check what needs to be done?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to run those click events each page load? Also, what do those click events do?